# Em que pontos ArrayAccess não se assemelha com o array nativo do PHP?

Tags: php, array

Eu sei que o `ArrayAccess` expõe uma interface de acesso a alguns elementos do objeto como se fosse um *array*

Exemplo:

```
class ListObject implements ArrayAccess{

    protected $storage;

    public function offsetSet($key, $value)
    {
        $this->storage[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function &offsetGet($key)
    {
        return $this->storage[$key];
    }   

    public function offsetUnset($key)
    {
        unset($this->storage[$key]);
    }   

    public function offsetExists($key)
    {
        return array_key_exists($key, $this->storage);
    }
}

$list = new ListObject;

$list[1] = 'Primeiro';

$list[2] = 'Segundo';
```

Porém, quando vou testar a existência de alguns elements, esse é o retorno:

```
var_dump(array_key_exists(2, $list)); // retorna false e não gera erros :\

var_dump(isset($list[2])); // true
```

E em algumas outras funções também houve erros ao tentar utilizar o objeto que implementa `ArrayAccess`.

- Se eu estivesse em um sistema onde os dados do banco fossem retornados por um array e eu quisesse implementar esse `ListObject`, eu poderia ter problemas em mudar apenas o retorno (sem ter que mudar verificações como `in_array` e `array_search` ou `array_key_exists` existentes nesse sistema)?

Ou teria que fazer mais implementações - como `Countable`, `IteratorAggregate` e afins ?

Exemplo:

```
 DB::table('tabela')->get();

    // array(0 => array('id' => 1, 'nome' => 2))

 DB::table('tabela')->get(); 
 // ListObject(['id' => 1, 'nome' => 2]);
```

- `ArrayAccess` apenas "simula" a interface de um array, porém ela não retorna os resultados esperados para as funções do `array` nativo?

Enfim, quais são as limitações de um objeto implementador de `ArrayAccess` em relação ao `array` nativo?

Answer (score 2):

Em resposta direta à pergunta...

Uma das grandes limitações desta Interface que tanto jeito dá, é no que se refere aos **arrays multi dimensionais**. Ou seja a sua implementação não pode ser direta.

exemplo :

```
$bool = isset($arr[1][2]);
```

Válido num array comum em PHP e tratada de forma simples e direta, mas o mesmo não pode acontecer pelo ArrayAccess. Para mim a única forma de resolver será:

```
$bool = isset($arr[[1, 2]]);
```

Terá de implementar internamente o mecanismo que permita esta forma e há no `stackoverflow` algumas soluções. Mas nenhuma delas é uma solução **ArrayAccess** pura.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO:**

Encontrei esta pergunta em aberto à qual respondi. Pelo que parece ficou dúvida no que descrevi. Encontrei um código que pode exemplificar o que mencionei, pelo aqui acrescento à minha resposta:

A class em PHP que implemente o descrito:

```
<?php 
   class MultiArrayAccess implements ArrayAccess {
    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        echo "  EXISTS ";
        print_r($offset);
        echo "\n";
    }
    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        echo "  GET ";
        print_r($offset);
        echo "\n";
        return $this;
    }
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        echo "  SET ";
        print_r($offset);
        echo " ";
        print_r($value);
        echo "\n";
    }
    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        echo "  UNSET ";
        print_r($offset);
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

depois a sua utilização:

```
<?php
    $multiArrayAccess = new MultiArrayAccess();

    echo "EXISTS:\n";
    isset($multiArrayAccess[1][2]);

    echo "GET:\n";
    $multiArrayAccess[3][4];

    echo "SET:\n";
    $multiArrayAccess[5][6] = 7;

    echo "UNSET:\n";
    unset($multiArrayAccess[8][9]);
```

resultado:

```
EXISTS:
  GET 1
  EXISTS 2
GET:
  GET 3
  GET 4
SET:
  GET 5
  SET 6 7
UNSET:
  GET 8
  UNSET 9
```

Como referi antes, não há uma solução real para este problema. Eu pensei sobre uma variável protegida que colecta os valores de $ offset. Se o utilizador da sua classe só usa `offsetExists`, `offsetSet` ou `offsetUnset` isso iria funcionar. Mas nunca pode saber se a chamada actual do `offsetGet` é o último ou se haverá mais um.

Portanto, sei que existem várias soluções para o problema mas nenhuma é uma implementação pura do `ArrayAccess` como por mim mencionado.

Comment: Amigo, `$arr[[1, 2]]` gera um `Illegal offset type` tanto para `array` como para `ArrayAccess`. O que você quis dizer ?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters claro que gera... como referi a implementação não pode ser directa! Terás de implementar a lógica para obter o offset de um array e não de uma variável como esperado pelo ArrayAccess. A única forma respeitando o interface ArrayAccess é a forma que coloquei. entendes? respondi foi à pergunta.... Quais a limitações!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters atualizei a minha resposta para ver se te consigo "iluminar" para o problema que descrevi... espero ter ajudado!